# Оптимизация ListView в Android

Tags: java, android, picasso

Есть `ListView`, там список видео с превью изображением, для загрузки привьюешек я использую библиотеку [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Дело в том что там может быть около 100 видео, и при прокрутке в конец списка (а потом нужно подгрузить ещё), занято примерно 20мб оперативной памяти, мало того, после того как Activity со списком видео уже закрыто (вызвал `finish()`) и я на главном Activity без каких либо списков, память не освобождается. Все так же 20мб занято.

Вопрос: Как оптимизировать ListView ? То есть, удалять изображения, из оперативной памяти, ну или какие есть другие способы.

Спасибо.

Comment: память освободиться, когда придет GC. На утечки тестировали? Банальный вопрос - в активити нет статических ссылок? (ещё проще - в коде активити встречается слово static для полей?)

Comment: Нету. Но я отправляю Activity в адаптер, вот пример кода adapter = new Video(this, items); Просто в адаптере нужен Context для LayoutInflater

Comment: И для Picasso нужен Context

Comment: Адаптер живет дольше активити? или создается каждый раз вместе с активити?

Comment: Ну обычно так, создается активити, подгружается список из интернета, и вставляется в адаптер. По этому да, создается каждый раз вместе с активити

Comment: Настойчиво рекомендую потратить час времени, посмотреть это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk и разобраться с memory analyser. Он поможет найти причину потребления памяти.

Comment: Ну, банальный вопрос - используете ли вы паттерн ViewHolder для заполнения ListView?

Comment: Да) У меня и в RecyclerView такая же проблема